# Why is the www version of website not working properly?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, no-www

I'm facing a problem with the following website: https://www.rhythmandstrums.ie/

When I open the "www" version of it: https://www.rhythmandstrums.ie/ I get a bugged website, failing to open stylesheets and possibly other file sources, whereas if I open the website without the "www", everything works as expected: https://rhythmandstrums.ie/

Some considerations:

- This website is hosted in a Wordpress Multisite, so it shares the same configuration files as other websites, none of the other websites have this issue. So I was wondering if this could be a problem with redirection, although, again, none of the other websites have this problem and they share the same config files (including server block settings and such, it is in nginx).
- I have checked the DNS values and nameservers and everything looks fine (I took base from all the other websites that were set up in the same way, I can post a screenshot if it might be of help).
- This error also seems to happen in the Wordpress backend, with the admin dashboard not being able to load parts of plugins, it seems like it is looking where it doesn't exist.
- I have replaced instances of the www version of the url in the database, as I do with other websites as well, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.
- I have cleared cache a few times (both in the cache plugin and manually in the nginx server - manually deleting the contents of the cache folder), and since this has been going for a long time, I don't know if this is cache related, but any suggestion is highly appreciated. Again, all the configs, included the cache plugin settings are the same for all the other websites in the network, which none are having this issue.
- If I inspect the console when I'm accessing both versions of the website, www and non-www it seems like it's trying to pull information from different locations, but I can't figure out why it's doing that.

Guys, I hope this was not confusing, but let me know if you you would like to see screenshots or other info that might be relevant. Thanks so much in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The website with www. loads completely different .css files; _as you say in your last point._ There could be an issue in theme setup.

Comment: Maybe share the nginx conf